# Hive parquet compression doesn't work

Tags: hive, compression, parquet, snappy

Hive version 2.3

```
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;

CREATED TABLE (
*)  STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3 location'
TBLPROPERTIES ('parquet.compress'='SNAPPY');
```

I did above but the table output in s3 location is not compressed, I'm able to see the result by using cat, I also tried 'TBLPROPERTIES ('PARQUET.COMPRESS'='ZLIB');' that didn't work either. Does anyone know what's the best way to compress parquet using hive? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
SET mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;


CREATED TABLE (*)  STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 's3 location';
```

you can also set other compression formats. List of compression

1. gzip - org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec
2. bzip2 - org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec
3. LZO - com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec
4. Snappy - org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
5. Deflate -org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DeflateCodec

From the above list, Snappy is NOT a default one, DeflateCodec is the default.
You can confirm this by running

```
hive> SET mapred.output.compression.codec;
```

Comment: I tired what you said above, added SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
SET mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK; to my hive script but the output is still not compressed. I could open the file and be able to look at the content directly.

Comment: Still trying to figure this out.